# How to manipulate the output of a .jar file and print it in a file or PHP variable

Tags: php, linux, shell, jar, jmx

I'm trying to manipulate the output of `jmxcmd.jar`

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/rpteira/jmxcmd.jar - my_machine:myport mybeanname > out.txt
```

This prints in the `out.txt` file a list with all the available attributes and commands of `mybeanname` but when I want to execute an special command of `mybeanname` I see the result in the console but not in the `out.txt` file. For example:

/usr/bin/java -jar /home/rpteira/jmxcmd.jar - my_machine:myport mybeanname getSomeStuff > out.txt

The shell output is something similar to this, but nothing in the file.

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss -0400 de.layereight.jmxcmd.Client getSomeStuff: 0
```

I want the 0 displayed above. To go further I would like to manipulate the result from php using `shell_exec()` but I can't find the output in my variable in this second case so I think this issue might be correlated.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your command line pattern from

```
cmd > out.txt
```

to

```
cmd &> out.txt
```

This will output both, standard output and errors, into out.txt.